# Meaning of bold capital D

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I would like to know the (asymptotic) properties of a Kernel Density Estimation. As a result, I was reading an [article from Nadaraya (1964)](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/1109069?casa_token=hSjJmtiWSigAAAAA%3AMH5o4kHdQ54SFaXHmKBO-XZT8MXuFfgzhiF_3RMw1jA6grgc5hulFylvqUMduLDoVUJzLEjzmwE&). In this article, a bold capital D ($\textbf{D}$) is used and apparently, it is assumed that the reader knows what this means. However, I am a bit puzzled. From reading on the internet, it usually refers to the derivative, but that seems odd to me in this particular case. To me, it seems more likely that is refers to the variance. (so maybe it comes from [standard] Deviation?)

What is meant by the $\textbf{D}$? Is this a common notation?

Here is the important passage of the article, with the capital D highlighted by the red rectangle:

[image: snippit of article Nadaraya (1964)]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$D$ is the standard Russian symbol for variance.  If you look at the wikipedia article on [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) and click on the tab for getting the Russian [version](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B) of the page, you will see that the Russian term for "variance" is "Дисперсия" or "dispersion".

Answer (score 1):

Upon reading the article, I think $\mathbf{D}$ refers to the variance. Equation (4) of the said article looks strikingly similar to the central limit theorem.